# [Ljava.lang.String;@5d79a22d result

Tags: java

When I run my program and type in the inputs the result is `[Ljava.lang.String;@5d79a22d`
I'm not sure what this means or why it is happening. 
This is part of my program:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
//first input
System.out.println("Enter your first input: ");
String first = s.nextLine();
String[] firstsplit = first.split(", ");
//second input
System.out.println("Enter your second input: ");
String second = s.nextLine();
String[] secondsplit = second.split(", ");
//third input
System.out.println("Enter your third input: ");
String third = s.nextLine();
String[] thirdsplit = third.split(", ");
//fourth input
System.out.println("Enter your fourth input: ");
String fourth = s.nextLine();
String[] fourthsplit = fourth.split(", ");
//fifth input
System.out.println("Enter your fifth input: ");
String fifth = s.nextLine();
String[] fifthsplit = fifth.split(", ");
//declares array of numbers for whites with given numbers

String[] subset1white= Arrays.copyOfRange(firstsplit, 1, Integer.parseInt(firstsplit[0]));
System.out.println(subset1white);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subset1white));`

Comment: What you're seeing is the native implementation of .toString() on an array object.  Suggest you either follow ZouZou's advice, or learn how to loop through the array printing each item on a separate line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This because you're calling `toString` method of a regular array

Try this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subset1white));
```

Comment: +1, you got it a minute before me. :P

Comment: Then you should be faster next time ;)

Comment: I was busy getting a link to the method and adding `import java.util.Arrays;`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`Arrays.toString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method, like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toSting(subset1white));
```

Make sure to put

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

at the top of your class. By default, printing an array will use [`Object`'s `toString()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), which returns

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

`Arrays.toString(Object[])` will return a string like this:

```
[abc, 123, def, 456]
```